# Why doesnt the StreamBuilder update the PDFView widget?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-streambuilder

Im new to flutter and stuck at the following problem, hope someone can help:

I am trying to build an App where the Presenter opens a pdf file and the Viewer can join the Presentation. The viewer gets the PDF file, opens it, and gets constant updates on the currently opened page (from the Presenter).

I set up a firebaseauth, firebase realtime database and firebase storage, authenticating the user throug a login, uploading and downloading the pdf to storage and writing the currentPage into realtime database. This part is working fine.

I am currently stuck for days at my pdf viewer client part, where i wrapped a StreamBuilder around the PDF Widget from the flutter_pdfview package, expecting it to update the Page opened by the widget.The Stream listens to the database entry written from the presenter "page".

```
body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: _firestore
              .collection('pdfControl')
              .doc(loggedInUser.uid)
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
              print(snapshot.data?['page']);
              var page = snapshot.data!['page'];
              currentPage = page;
              print ('currentpage:  $currentPage');
              //_pdfController.setPage(page);

              return PDFView(
```

I did try to check if i get changes from the realtimedb snapshot.

```
`if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
              print(snapshot.data?['page']);`
```

is working. The Output is 1, 2, 3, 2 etc

But the

```
`return PDFView(
                  filePath: widget.pdfPath,
                  autoSpacing: true,
                  enableSwipe: true,
                  pageSnap: true,
                  swipeHorizontal: true,
                  defaultPage: currentPage!,
                  onError: (error) {
                    print(error);
                  },
                  onPageError: (page, error) {
                    print('$page: ${error.toString()}');
                  },
                  onRender: (_pages) {
                    setState(() {
                      pages = _pages!;
                      isReady = true;
                      print ('currpage:  $currentPage');
                    });
                  },
                  onViewCreated: (PDFViewController vc)  {
                    setState(() {
                      _pdfController = vc;
                      _controller.complete(vc);
                      vc.setPage(currentPage);
                      print(page);
                      print(snapshot.data?['page']);
                    });

                  },
                  onPageChanged: (int? page, int? total) {
                    setState(() {
                      currentPage = page!;
                    });

                  });`
```

It is not swaping the page. when the snapshot.data?['page'] gets an update.

Why?

I thought the StreamBuilder would listen on the

```
stream: _firestore
              .collection('pdfControl')
              .doc(loggedInUser.uid)
              .snapshots(),
```

and rebuilds the widgets it is wrapped around on changes in the db collection?

```
`I/flutter (12485): currentpage:  3
E/FrameEvents(12485): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(12485): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
I/flutter (12485): 3
I/flutter (12485): currentpage:  3
E/FrameEvents(12485): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
I/chatty  (12485): uid=10123(com.example.screenshare_project) RenderThread identical 21 lines
E/FrameEvents(12485): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
I/flutter (12485): 4
I/flutter (12485): currentpage:  4
I/flutter (12485): 4
I/flutter (12485): currentpage:  4
I/flutter (12485): 3
I/flutter (12485): currentpage:  3
I/flutter (12485): 3
I/flutter (12485): currentpage:  3`
```

this is my output

I really need some help here...can someone please explain this behavior to me? What am i doing wrong?

PS: The setState lines are my desperate attempt for another solution (not working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`defaultPage` is only used at the time the PDF file is loaded, after that it won't control what page is currently being displayed.

Use the controller to change the page.

```
_pdfController.setPage(page);
```

Also you don't need to wrap `PDFView` inside a `StreamBuilder`. Just listen to the stream with the `listen` method, and call that `setPage` method in the callback.

Comment: thanks for the answer. how can you tell that it is only called when loaded?

Comment: From the [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_pdfview/latest/flutter_pdfview/PDFView/defaultPage.html)

Comment: Ok. I now changed the code to this:   @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _firestore
        .collection('pdfControl')
        .doc(loggedInUser.uid)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((snapshot) {
      var page = snapshot.data()?['page'];
      _pdfController.setPage(page);
    });  as you suggested. now i get the error: Unhandled Exception: LateInitializationError: Field '_pdfController@43348932' has not been initialized.  I guess   late PDFViewController _pdfController; is the problem here? How do i solve this?

Comment: The stream may emit values before the `_pdfController` is initialized. Don't use late, just make `_pdfController` nullable: `PDFViewController? _pdfController;` and call the setPage like this: `_pdfController?.setPage(page);`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it with implementing the suggestions from Dhafin Rayhan:

(StreamBuilder to listener and nullable PDFViewController):

```
PDFViewController? _pdfController;

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser();

    _firestore
        .collection('pdfControl')
        .doc(loggedInUser.uid)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((snapshot) {
      var page = snapshot.data()?['page'];
      print(page);
      _pdfController?.setPage(page);
    });

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: PDFView(
          filePath: widget.pdfPath,
          autoSpacing: true,
          enableSwipe: true,
          pageSnap: true,
          swipeHorizontal: true,
          onError: (error) {
            print(error);
          },
          onPageError: (page, error) {
            print('$page: ${error.toString()}');
          },
          onRender: (page) {
            
          },
          onViewCreated: (PDFViewController vc) {
            _controller.complete(vc);
            _pdfController = vc;
            
          },
          onPageChanged: (int? page, int? total) {
            
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Thanks a lot!